# Varying performance measurements for Metal kernel

Tags: swift, metal

I am trying out compute with Metal and measuring performance for a few of my kernels. Here's what I am using to measure:

```
self.measureMetrics(XCTestCase.defaultPerformanceMetrics(), automaticallyStartMeasuring: false) {
    do {
        let commandBuffer = device.newCommandQueue().commandBuffer()

        try reverse(library, commandBuffer: commandBuffer, dataBuffer: dataBuffer, bufferSize: uint(data.count), elementSize: uint(sizeof(Int)))

        self.startMeasuring()

        commandBuffer.commit()
        commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()

        self.stopMeasuring()
    } catch {
        print("Exception")
    }
}
```

The `reverse` function itself does nothing but encode commands into the buffer using a compute command encoder. The `dataBuffer` is in `StorageModeShared` if it matters.

I am getting performance results as `[0.015457, 0.004573, 0.005718, 0.006153, 0.005495, 0.005555, 0.006460, 0.005946, 0.006363, 0.007379]`. Given that the same task is performed every time, I don't see a reason why the first measurement is so high.

Any ideas why the time taken for the first measurement is so different from the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things happening in your benchmark I'm pretty sure:

- The first measuring is about three times longer than the rest. This happens in a lot of benchmarks, usually because the CPU needs to warm up before it has it's full power, could also be some initial tasks which only get executed when you first call some function (lazy execution). It's pretty obvious that it only affects the first one, so you don't really have to bother
- There are some fluctuations in all measurements of about ~20%. I believe this is due to the connection from CPU to GPU: They are (relatively) far away and don't operate on the same level, which means there can be some inconsistencies. You shouldn't worry about this because the standard deviation of your measurements isn't very high.

Conclusion: Your performance measurements are totally fine

Also maybe you can change it to start measuring after the commit, just to see what it does

Comment: Thanks! I ran it a few times before measuring to warm it up and its all right now... :)